# Wireless firmware not loading

Tags: wireless, intel, intel-wireless, intel-nuc

I have an Intel-NUC-Kit-NUC6i7KYK and I installed Ubuntu server 16.04
It doesn't find wifi network IP when I do `ifconfig -a`

I looked into `/var/log/kern.log` and I see below message

```
Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-17.ucode failed with error -2
Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-18.ucode failed with error -2
Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode failed with error -2
```

What am I missing? I don't see any `iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode or 18 or 17` in `/lib/firmware` (as it can't load)

EDIT:

output of `dmesg | grep iwl`

```
enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-17.ucode failed with error -2
Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-18.ucode failed with error -2
Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode failed with error -2
loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Detected Intel R Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mum-rs'
wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: What is the kernel version? It should load the 16 or 21.

Comment: 4.4.0-62-generic

Comment: how do I make sure it loads 16 or 21?

Comment: Please post the output of `dmesg | grep iwl` TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: @Pilot6 added the output

Comment: So it is loaded. All is good with the firmware.

Comment: then way don't I see the network? also there is no iwlwifi-8000C-17.ucode etc file in /lib/firmware

Comment: This is a different question. It is OK that 17 does not exist. This is how the kernel module works. it looks for max version, it does not always exist.

Comment: How have you set up networking, the SSID, password, etc.? Have you used `/etc/network/interfaces`? If so, may we see it?

Answer (score 2):

The firmware version 16 is loading OK.

Your problem is not related to the firmware.

The 4.4 kernel module tries to load firmware starting with 19, but there is only 16 available. It is made by design.

Answer (score 0):

There are some firmware missing. Please see this bug report - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1704799 - there are also links and information about workaround, at least in my case it worked. Hopefully you can download missing firmware to /lib/firmware/ folder, use sudo depmod -a command and then reload the kernel module (sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi).